# add buttons between and under the mid of two div

Tags: html, css, button, position

how i can add TWO buttons between two div like this?
[image]

Comment: place the two buttons inside a div, and give that div a negative margin-top, ex: margin-top: -15px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative margins. Let's say the buttons have a 30px height: apply a margin-top of -15px and a margin-bottom of -15px to the buttons container (if you want it in the middle for example)

```css
body,html{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.div1 {
  background: tomato;
  height: 100px;
}

.div2 {
  background: grey;
  height: 100px;
}

.buttons{
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  text-align: center;
}
button {
  height: 30px;      
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button 2</button>
</div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```